# Cordova + Android: Intercepting streaming webm resource

Tags: android, cordova, intercept

I am using Cordova v3.4.0 with Android 4.4. My web app defines a video tag element for a webm stream.

```
<video src="https://stream.server.com:1234/video_rgb" type="video/webm"
</video>
```

I am trying to intercept the request to stream.server.com:1234 and some auth headers. Once the headers are added, I return the web response in this way.

*Cordova Activity*

```
this.appView.setWebViewClient(new CordovaWebViewClient(this, this.appView) {

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

            if (shouldIntercept(url)) {
                LOG.i(TAG, "Intercepting " + url + " request");
                return handleRequest(url);
            } else {
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
            }
        }
    });

// handleRequest()
httpGet = generateHttpGet(url, authHeaders); // Returns org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
return new WebResourceResponse(contentTypeValue, encodingValue, responseInputStream);
```

The request goes through successfully but the video never renders. When I click play, nothing happens. Sometimes the application just hangs. Android logs dont show anything useful except that the request succeeds with content-type: video/webm and content length = -1. Im not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Note: This works for a webm video with a fixed length or for static assets like images.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I'm seeing very similar behaviour. Observing request intercept and server logs where videos are hosted, it appears that webview is making multiple requests in order to play the video. In my case, only the first request gets intercepted by the native code (which works correctly, and auth headers are added in). Subsequent requests are not intercepted, and thus end up being invalid.